# the memory is released when passing to unordered_map by rvalue

Tags: c++, list, unordered-map, rvalue

I bulit it with `-std=c++17` and tried both `g++` and `clang++` such as `clang++ -std=c++17 <file>`. It showed the same results.

#### unordered_map

Pass an unordered_map to rvalue parameter in a function and assign it to another reference. And the memory is not allowed out of the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

typedef unordered_map<string, string> kw_t;

struct Bar {
    kw_t &foo;
    string bar;
};

list<Bar> bars;

void test(kw_t &&foo) {
    cout << &foo["a"] << endl;
    bars.emplace_back(Bar { .foo = foo, .bar = "bar" });
    cout << &bars.front().foo["a"] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test({{"a", "b"}});
    cout << &bars.front().foo["a"] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it has output:

```
0x1f3ded8
0x1f3ded8
[1]    9776 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.o
```

#### list

But for other classes, such as list or self defined struct, the code can work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef list<string> args_t;


struct Bar {
    args_t &foo;
    string bar;
};

list<Bar> bars;

void test(args_t &&foo) {
    cout << &foo.front() << endl;
    bars.emplace_back(Bar { .foo = foo, .bar = "bar" });
    cout << &bars.front().foo.front() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test({"a", "b"});
    cout << &bars.front().foo.front() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It printed:

```
0x15a7ec0
0x15a7ec0
0x15a7ec0
```

Why can the second one work but the first not?

Edit1:

clang version 7.1.0

g++ (GCC) 9.3.0

Comment: You create a dangling reference `foo` in both cases. So neither of them work.

Comment: @user7860670 But the second case worked. Is it an erroneous behavior for compiler?

Comment: I thought that references should be initialized on declaration. Is it changed over new versions of C++?

Comment: Second version does not work, just like the first one. The only difference is that in first case UB manifests itself in segmentation fault.

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet All the references are properly initialized here.

Comment: Generally, if you're unsure about whether it's a compiler error, it's not.

Comment: Use Address sanitizer on your program (even the one appearing to work), like this: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/51fz4T)

Comment: @user7860670 Where is the initialization for &foo under struct? Am I missing something?

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet Initialization happens inside of curly braces `Bar { .foo = foo,` then object is copied to container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can the second one work but the first not?

In both cases, behaviour of the program is undefined. So, it "can" or "may" or "is allowed to" *appear* to work (for whatever you perceive as "woking"). Or to not "work". Or to have any other behaviour.

To clarify, the lifetime of the temporary object to which the reference `bars.front().foo` was bound has ended, and so the reference is invalid. Calling a member function through the invalid reference results in undefined behaviour.

> Is it an erroneous behavior for compiler?

No. The compiler is behaving correctly. Your programs however are broken.